# AVAudioPlayer's prepareToPlay Method

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, avaudioplayer

If I preload a sound using the AVAudioPlayer's `.prepareToPlay()` method multiple times, does that use more memory for each time I call it or is it smart enough to only allocate the memory once if the audio is already loaded into memory?

I have several of the same object in given level that I need to play a sound for when the player touches it. I have created an AVAudioPlayer instance for each object, and the way my code is set up, I use the `.prepareToPlay()` method for each of those objects to preload the sound.

This code gets executed for each object needing to play the sound in the level:

```
do {
   levelObject.soundFXPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("SoundFXFile", ofType: "mp3")!))
   levelObject.soundFXPlayer.prepareToPlay()
}
catch {
    print("Error in preloading sound effects")
}
```

Comment: Can you add some source code? It will make it clearer for people to help you.

Comment: That is why we have profilers,  just check your memory usage (You can even use the ones built into XCode to test this)

Comment: Why are you using AVAudioPlayer for spritekit?  Just use `SKAction playSoundWithFilename`

Comment: I've tried using SKAction and SKAudioNode and at least 1 / 10 times there's still a big frame rate drop when the sound gets played, like the sound isn't preloading. Just trying other options.

Comment: are you doing it correctly? Make sure you cache it before using it

Comment: I believe I do it correctly. I create a class variable: `let playPopSFX = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("PopSFX.mp3", waitForCompletion: false) ` then when I'm ready to use it, I say `self.runaction(self.playPopSFX)`

Comment: convert to .caf audio format:: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CAFSpec/CAF_intro/CAF_intro.html :: and don't worry about preload, it should be smart enough to load only once, as you're referencing it, not treating it as a value type and copying it. I understand why you're using AVAudioPlayer instead of Actions. They're bugged.